# Textfield Centering in the List

Tags: html, css

I have implemented following UI, however it does not look good. I would like to achieve my textfield to be centered in the corresponding list item. Or is there any other way to achieve the same functionality with another way such as table or grid?

This is what I want to get:

[image]

This is what I got

[image]

```
 input[type="text"]{
        display:inline;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-right:1px;
        width: 35px;
        text-align:center;
        clear: left;
}


label {
       color: white;
       display: inline-block;
       font: normal 8px
}

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

li  {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

.parent:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: black;
   }



<body>

<div id="ValueDiv">

<ul>
 <li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="firstTF"/>
<label for="first">First</label>
</li>
<li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="secondTF"/>
<label for="second">Second</label>
 </li>
<li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="thirdTF"/>
<label for="third">Third</label>
</li>
 <li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fourthTF"/>
<label for="fourth">Fourth</label>
</li>
<li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fifthTF"/>
<label for="fifth">Fifth</label>
</li>
<li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="sixthTF"/>
<label for="sixth">Sixth</label>
 </li>        
<li class="parent">
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="seventhTF"/>
<label for="seventh">Seventh</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist in using that structure you need to add `float:left;` to `label`

**BUT** ...

You can and should use tables to display information in an ordered fashion like the one depicted:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To achieve those borders you should look into `border` and `padding` css properties

Alternatively you could also use the `dl` element like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>First</dt>
  <dd>10</dd>
  <dt>Second</dt>
  <dd>20</dd>
  <dt>Third</dt>
  <dd>30</dd>
</dl>
```